# Merge two rows with parent and child ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just started using SQL and I bumped into this problem. There must be a very easy solution I assume. All relations are saved in the relations table. Then there is a parent and a child. The parent being a company and the child being a contact of this company. Every relation has a RelID but the relation_relation table is used to split company and contact.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the company and the contact into one row like so:

```
| nameCompany | nameContact |
-----------------------------
|random B.V.  | emmma       |
|random B.V.  | jason       |
```

I have two tables which I want to query. These are simplified versions with a 
few example values:

```
CREATE TABLE relations_relations (parentRelID INT, childRelID INT); 

INSERT INTO `relations_relations` VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `relations_relations` VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `relations_relations` VALUES (1, 3);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE relations (RelID, nameContact, nameCompany); 

INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES (1, NULL, random B.V.);
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES (2, emma, NULL);
INSERT INTO `relations` VALUES (3, jason, NULL);
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server?

Comment: MySQL-server 2015

Answer (score 1):

You need to `JOIN` the relation table to itself via the relations_relations table:

```sql
SELECT   p.nameCompany
        ,c.nameContact
FROM relations p
    INNER JOIN relations_relations rr
        ON p.RelID = rr.parentRelID
    INNER JOIN relations c
        ON c.RelID = rr.childRelID
```

Comment: how are you referencing p.parentRelID and p.childRelID since they're not in the table relations? I'm trying your method but it can' t find the colomns parentRelID and childRelID

Comment: as you can see in my answer, you got your message accros. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out myself. 
you're supposed to join two time and use a different condition 
both times.

in this problem it should be:

```
Select *
from Test_Relations_Relations a
    inner join Test_relations b
        on a.childrelID = b.RelID
    inner join Test_relations c
        on a.parentrelID = b.relID
```